# Url amigables usando .htaccess y PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

Hola resulta que intento que esta url :

```
http://localhost:8080/acortador/go.php?id=ac5b5
```

Termine así :

```
http://localhost:8080/acortador/ac5b5
```

Usando .htaccess que asta el momento lo tengo asi .

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ go.php?id=$1 [NC,L]


<Files ~ "(.json)">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

Igual busco como proteger los archivos .json  pero no funciona ninguno el .htaccess se encuentra dentro de la carpeta "acortador" y la variable $id la la capturo así .

```
$codi = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';
```

Igual usando .htaccess me gustaría eliminar de las url los .php

Ejemplo
Esto

```
http://localhost:8080/acortador/admin.php
```

Por esto

```
http://localhost:8080/acortador/admin/
```

Espero me podáis dar una idea de como lograrlo y claro espero haber sido claro en lo que deseo hacer .

Answer (score 0):

Hace unos días pregunté algo similar. Te dejaré un código y mi pregunta original, quizá te sirva.
Probablemente la parte que mas te interese es ésta:

```
# encender rewrite engine
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Lo que hace ésta configuracion es que si tu tienes http://midominio.com/pagina.php puedas escribir simplemente http://midominio.com/pagina y cargue el contenido.

Ahora bien, es de hacer notar que no lleva una diagonal al final. Si colocas la diagonal al final, intentará acceder a un directorio y mandara a un 404.
No se realmente como colocar la diagonal al final, pero creo que esto es un buen comienzo.

También te dejo el link de la pregunta que te decía.
Quería convertir:

http://midominio.com/?page=pagina

En

http://midominio.com/pagina

Para ésto, solo sería de cambiar la última linea anterior por:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=/$1 [L,QSA]
```

[[Usar una variable GET para acceder a una pagina usando HTACCESS y PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/263577/usar-una-variable-get-para-acceder-a-una-pagina-usando-htaccess-y-php/263755#263755][1])

Saludos cordiales.

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro si esto es lo que necesitas, pero para hacer tantas validaciones necesitas mas de una re dirección.

Suponiendo que tienes estos tres archivos dentro de /acortador/

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /acortador/


# 1. Redirigimos index.php a solo /
# ------------------------------------------------------------
RewriteRule ^(.*)(index\.php|index/)$ $1 [R=301,L]


# 2. Convertimos el parametro ID en carpeta si es go.php
# ------------------------------------------------------------
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /go.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/? [R=301,L]


# 3. Redirigimos todos los PHP a solo FILE/
# ------------------------------------------------------------
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/ [R=301,L]


# 4. Si la carpeta no existe dirigimos a INDEX
# ------------------------------------------------------------
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?p=$1 [L]


# 5. Bloqueamos acceso directo a archivos JSON
# ------------------------------------------------------------
<FilesMatch "\.(json)$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

$pagina = str_replace( '/', '', $_GET['p'] );

if( $pagina == 'admin' ) {

    // Logica del Administrador
    echo 'Este es el administrador';

} else {

    // Busca y Regresa el JSON
    if( file_exists( $pagina.'.json' ) ) {
        echo 'JSON Existe...<hr>';
        echo file_get_contents( $pagina.'.json' );

    } else {
        echo 'El JSON No Existe ... Ver la Pagina Principal';

    }

}
```

**ac5b5.json**

```
{"ejemplo":"de htaccess"}
```

Entonces las re direcciones serán así:

De https://localhost/acortador/go.php?id=ac5b5 llega a https://localhost/acortador/ac5b5/ y muestra el contenido de ac5b5.json

De https://localhost/acortador/admin.php llega a https://localhost/acortador/admin/ y muestra la lógica del admin

El acceso directo a los archivos JSON marca un error, por ejemplo https://localhost/acortador/ac5b5.json

Cualquier otra URL te muestra la lógica de la pagina principal.

Estoy seguro que el código se puede mejorar, pero espero te ayude.

Comment: Tu respuesta esta bastante completa pero no da la función que se requiere . por que al ingresar a admin.PHP  me cambia la url a midominio.con/go/p=/ y eso es un error

Comment: Revisa que el htaccess sea exactamente como lo puse arriba, y quita cualquier otra instrucción para probar. Acabo de probarlo y funciona exactamente como debe. Borra el cache del explorador por que puede ser por eso. No olvides las directivas [NC] para ignorar si la URL es con mayúsculas o no. Si no es el cache, entonces es algo que tienes adicional. Recuerda que no debe existir el archivo admin.php en el directorio, yo te recomiendo que solo dejes estos tres archivos. Esta es solo una demo para las URLs no es tu proyecto completo.

Answer (score -1):

Mira, intenta esto:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
<FilesMatch "\.(json)$">
 Order Allow,Deny
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Deberías de explicar un poco tu código . para entenderlo mejor igual no logró ver el que parte incluyes mi pregunta .

Comment: Qué es lo que no se entiende? Activo el sobreescribir, pido el formato de archivo que está abriendo la página y se cambia el formato, después denegó el acceso a los archivos de formato .json... No es lo que querías?

Comment: Bueno esto . http://localhost:8080/acortador/go.php?id=ac5b5. Debería cambiar por http://localhost:8080/acortador/ac5b5. Igual los .json aun se pueden descargar . al ponerlo en la url

Comment: Te lo explicaria pero ando del móvil, mejor pásate por aquí https://juanluismora.es/seo/url-limpias-con-php.html , espero esto te sirva :)

Comment: Mañana edito mí repuesta agregando las partes esenciales, es que justo me encontraba en el móvil, saludos.