# Usar una variable GET para acceder a una pagina usando HTACCESS y PHP

Tags: php, web, .htaccess

Buen día.
Tengo una configuración .htaccess que me permite por ejemplo si tengo http://example.com/pagina.php acceder a esa pagina escribiendo http://example.com/pagina

Ahora bien, la cuestión esta en que quiero hacer algo similar pero esta vez utilizando GET.
Si tengo
http://example.com/?page=paginadestino
pueda acceder a esto escribiendo
http://example.com/paginadestino

y que al mismo tiempo me deje usar otros items de GET
http://example.com/paginadestino?nombre=valor
o
http://example.com/paginadestino&nombre=valor
o algo del estilo, pero que pueda utilizarlo con $_GET["nombre"] en PHP.

Dejo abajo mi configuración de htaccess (la que permite lo que explique al principio):

```
# encender rewrite engine
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

<Files .conf>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
<Files .settings>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Saludos Cordiales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí te dejo el código funcionando:

```
#código htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=/$1 [L,QSA]

<Files .conf>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
<Files .settings>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Y con este archivo index.php puedes probar su funcionamiento

```
<?php 
//Ejemplos de uso para verificar:
//http://example.com/pagina1
//http://example.com/pagina2
//http://example.com/pagina1?otroget=valor1
echo "Tu página: ".$_GET["page"]."<br>";
echo "Otro GET : ".$_GET["otroget"];
```

Comment: Ésto me funcionó de maravilla! Muchas gracias!

Comment: @Lsyk4 si la pregunta te ha sido util, por favor marcala como la respuesta, así ayudamos a los demás usuarios y visitantes.